# How to pass a javascript variable via query string to a html test file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, variables, query-string

I have a tricky problem....

So within my Rails app, I want to pass a javascript variable from a specific rails route via query-string to a test.html document. My goal is, that every time I open the html.test document the html.test document is opened with the query string in the header, taken from the page of the route.

Is that even possible? This is what I came up with, and it's not very good so far:

in my rails view:

```
<script>
var value ="<%= current_organization.uid %>";
var queryString = "?" + value ;
window.location.href = "capybara-test.html" + queryString;
</script>
```

note that it is the value that I want to pass on to the capybara-test.html file.

In my html file within the header:

```
var queryString = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search);
queryString = queryString.substring(1);
console.log(queryString);
```

So when I open my localhost with that route this is actually redirecting me from my page to my html document and prints out my variable.

So far so good.

But I don't want a redirect. I want that to happen when I open the html document. I want to open the html document, and that should dynamically get via query-string the id of my rails app.

Any Ideas? Is that even the right way to do it or am I completely wrong? Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks....

Comment: What do you mean by "open the html document"? you are "opening" it with the redirect. Maybe you want an ajax request but I don't really understand what you want. Read about AJAX, maybe it fits your need.

Comment: thanks for the hint. Well the idea is that later on I will open the html via Capybara. So in production mode I don't want a redirect there. In testing mode I want to get the ID dynamically (since it changes everytime someone logs himself in) from that page. Does that make sense?

Comment: or is there a way to only run the <script> ... </script> in test environment and not in development/production env?

Comment: If your script is inside an .erb view, you can do `<%- if Rails.env.test? %><script>....</script><% end %>` to only render the script while testing.

Comment: @arieljuod, thank you, that's gold!!